# How to format timestamp from mysql select query to exclude the unnecessary zeros in HH:MM:SS?

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting, timestamp, timespan

I have a select query:

```
string checkprogress = "SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,timestamp) FROM times";
```

Which in return gives me a format with unnecessary leading zeros...

```
00:01:39 //(hours:minutes:seconds)
```

How can I alter this query or alter my c# code so that my string excludes all the unnecessary zeros in the timestamp?

Keep in mind that if the time reaches over 24 hours, the string will become:

```
1.00:01:39 //(day.hours:minutes:seconds)
```

the format above is completely fine since a day value is incorporated, so the format change I'm looking for is strictly for when the DAY value is not in effect (A.K.A when time is under 23:59:59).

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn_t pretty, but it works.

```
SET @endDate = '2020-06-27 10:02:00';
SET @startDate = '2020-06-26 12:59:01';
SELECT 
CONCAT(
  IF(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) / 86400) > 0,CONCAT(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) / 86400), '.'),''),
  LPAD(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 86400)/3600),2,'0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 3600)/60),2,'0'), ':',
  LPAD((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 60),2,'0')
);
```

Result `21:02:59`

```
SET @endDate = '2020-06-27 10:02:00';
SET @startDate = '2020-06-26 09:59:01';
SELECT 
CONCAT(
  IF(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) / 86400) > 0,CONCAT(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) / 86400), '.'),''),
  LPAD(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 86400)/3600),2,'0'), ':',
  LPAD(FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 3600)/60),2,'0'), ':',
  LPAD((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @startDate, @endDate) % 60),2,'0')
)
```

Result `1.00:02:59`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 8+, you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('00:01:39', '^[0:]+(\\d)', '$1')
```

For earlier versions, you can call [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) twice, the first to trim leading `00:`s from the string, and then to trim any further leading `0`s:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(LEADING '00:' FROM '00:01:39'))
```

In both cases the output is

```
1:39
```

There is one caveat on the `TRIM` method, if the result can be `00:00:00` the output will be an empty string. That can either be dealt with in your application, or you can use an `IF` expression to check for it:

```
IF(TIMEDIFF(t1, t2) = '00:00:00', 0, TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TRIM(LEADING '00:' FROM TIMEDIFF(t1, t2))))
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bdea6e561b89323e890897721d55eb1)